# Javascript Context Reinstate

Tags: c#, javascript, v8

I have a javascript context that I serialize by doing

```
JSON.serialize(this);
```

Is it possible to then do something like (I know this doesn't work)

```
this = JSON.parse(serializedstring);
```

Ideally I'd like that object to just get instantiated back into the global namespace.  Is there a way to do that without iterating through each of the objects and re-declaring all those variables?

this is actually being done within a c# project using javascript.net (V8 engine)

Comment: You can't assign to `this`. Not much else to say about it.

Comment: maaaan :-(  Refactoring Friday just got more interesting then.